# Suddenly unable to install anything after failing to install v4l2loopback-dkms - dpkg insists I must first reconfigure UEFI Secure Boot

Tags: uefi, dpkg, 21.10, obs-studio, v4l

Fresh install of 21.10. I decide to install OBS Studio. The guide on https://obsproject.com/wiki/install-instructions#linux says

> If you want virtual camera support you need v4l2loopback-dkms installed. You can install it with the following command:

```
$ sudo apt install v4l2loopback-dkms
```

Now, I don't currently *need* virtual camera support, I just thought "why the hell not". But the moment I issued that command, I got this screen:

[image]

When I click OK, I'm asked to "Enter a password for Secure Boot. It will be asked again after a reboot."

To be clear: I have *no* desire to mess around with boot stuff. I have a dual-boot laptop, and it is paramount that the Windows partition remains unscathed. I will certainly rather do without virtual cameras than messing with the boot system.

**THE PROBLEM**

-is that now I can't install *anything,* e.g.

```
$ sudo apt install zoom
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

-and when I run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` I get the whole "Configuring Secure Boot" dialog all over again.

*I don't want to enter a password for Secure Boot,* but until I do, I can't install anything.

**THE QUESTION**

How do I get out of this mess *without* entering a password for Secure Boot?

Comment: For any unsigned drivers including virtual ones like in this case you either (1) disable Secure Boot in uEFI (easier and preferable unless dual-booting with Windows 11) or (2) **do exactly as it says with MOK**. there's no 3rd option and neither has anything whatsoever to do with Windows or its partitions.

Comment: So basically what you're saying is that once this process is started, there's no going back? Now I *need* to finish this? I believe I'm currently dual-booting with Windows 10 Pro, but I might be upgraded to Windows 11 at some point.

Comment: Not at all. But if you don't do one of the two option your software won't work. If you're planning to have Windows 11 then you should keep Secure Boot enabled (it's a requirement). Then you should understand what MOK is and how to use it (it's self-explanatory) if you latter need to use any 3rd party unsigned drivers (including virtual, e.g. Virtualbox) like Nvidia's.

Comment: Okay. So - just to be clear - your recommendation is to go ahead with Secure Boot configuration, as it is *very* unlikely to cause problems with booting Windows?

Comment: Neither option affects Windows in any way. It's your decision between *not* using the software in this question or, if you really want it, then one of the aforementioned options must be done.